# C# How to Get o365 attachments with HTTP URI

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, office365

I have 10000s of strings in this format:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{Principal_Name}/messages/{Message_ID}/attachments
```

I need to figure out how to:

1. Use these URIs in C#, to access multiple user mailboxes
2. Using the Graph API; get all attachments (file, item, reference, inline)
3. Load each set of attachments into a list (or IEnumerable)

I'm working in a C# azure function, .Net Standard 2. Using App Authentication. (tenant/clientid/client secret). With a valid AccessToken.

How would C# be used to do this?

Comment: Pleas be clear what you are looking for, Are you trying to download attachment from other user mailbox? or you ar elooking to download attachment from one Email message.

Comment: I have 10000s of these strings that lead to many user mailboxes. So im trying to loop through this long list of URIs and get all of the attachments for each.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios where an app can get messages in another user's mail folder:

- If the app has application permissions, or,
- If the app has the appropriate delegated permissions from one user, and another user has shared a mail folder with that user, or, has given delegated access to that user. See details and an example.

**Permissions**

One of the following permissions is required to call this API. To learn more, including how to choose permissions, see Permissions.

- Permission type   Permissions (from least to most privileged)
- Delegated (work or school account)    Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite
- Delegated (personal Microsoft account)    Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite
  Application

If you have the API in below format :

GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{Message_ID}/attachments

All you need is service principal(Azure AD registered app with right set of permission which i mentioned above with valida Bearer token then you can simple call above api to get attachment.

API call : GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{Message_ID}/attachments
Authorization : Bearer {token.

You can refer this blog for getting the bearer token for the same:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/03/17/accessing-azure-app-services-using-azure-ad-bearer-token-2/

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-list-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope it helps.